# How to use Sprockets 2 with Rails 3.0.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I'm trying to use [these](https://gist.github.com/911003) [gists](https://gist.github.com/923998) to get Sprockets 2.0beta to work with a Rails 3.0.5 app in a similar way to how it works natively in Rails 3.1. Failing thoroughly so far--my app is finding the correct routes and files, and loading the initializer that extends Sprockets::Environment, but it's not parsing the //= require 'phu' lines in my application.js.

Can anyone enlighten me about Sprockets 2 with Rails 3.0?

Comment: looking forward for answers here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the same gists as a basis, and it works fine. I have made some changes though.
Maybe you can try that, see if it helps: https://gist.github.com/1112393

ps: I guess you solved it yourself since it's been a month...
I personally have another problem: [How to use Sprockets 2 with Rails 3.0.x (how to use precompiled assets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934195/how-to-use-sprockets-2-with-rails-3-0-x-how-to-use-precompiled-assets)
If you solved it already, or found another way to make this efficient on production, could you help me? Thanks.