# How to use Sprockets 2 with Rails 3.0.x (how to use precompiled assets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to **replicate the basics of the asset pipeline introduced in rails 3.1 in my rails 3.0 app**.

So far, I've got something like this:
https://gist.github.com/1112393.

It works great:

- I have my assets in app/assets/, lib/assets, vendor/assets...
- They're all served at /assets
- I can use everything sprockets 2 offers etc...

The thing is, I don't want the rails app to serve static assets. The server should do it.
That's why you can precompile assets in rails 3.1, if I understood correctly.
So I've made a rake task that does just that (using the precompile method of Sprockets::Environment). And it works, I have all my assets at /public/assets/.

For instance, I have

- application-02f8c96b342b4569513d0edf39ef55eb.css
- application-505e8f472350fb1e0d15f6ad2f5e0389.js
- gallery-icons-0e922050a85718fef3cd570df4eb5845.png

But in rails 3.1, you can do something like that in your style.css.scss.erb

```
background: url(<%= asset_path("gallery-icons.png") %>)
```

and you'd get

```
background: url(/assets/gallery-icons-0e922050a85718fef3cd570df4eb5845.png)
```

in the precompiled file.

Same for stylesheet_link_tag, javascript_link_tag which are overwritten in rails 3.1 to add the hash, if I'm not mistaken.

**How can I do this?**

Give me every idea you can have! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Josh answered me here: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/151

```
Assets = Sprockets::Environment.new(Rails.root) do |env|
    assets =  ["javascripts", "stylesheets", "images", "fonts"]
    paths =   ["app/assets/", "lib/assets/", "vendor/assets/" ].map{|p| assets.map{|f| "#{p}#{f}" } }.flatten

    paths.each{ |path| env.append_path path }

    env.static_root = Rails.root.join("public", "assets")
end
```

So basically, I have a rake task to precompile the assets:

```
namespace :assets do
    task :precompile => :environment do
        Assets.precompile(*Rails.application.config.assets.precompile)
    end
end
```

My problem was mainly to know how to request these assets.
The answer is quite simple:

```
Assets['application.js'].digest
```

Having the fingerprint, it's easy to get the filename.

I created helpers to include these assets: `sprockets_include_tag` and `sprockets_image_tag`.

Done deal.

(Although right now, I can't use these helpers in my stylesheets (style.css.scss.erb))

Comment: By the way, since then, I improved a little bit this stuff, by upgrading to the last version of sprockets, readding the deprecated precompile method, and making it return an asset manifest. I'm loading this manifest when I start the app, so that I dont have to rebuild the file paths with the fingerprint each time. Anyways... I hope I'll be able to move to 3.1 soon ^^.

Comment: where did you get the precompile method from? It's not there in Sprockets 2.0.0. And how did you make it return an asset manifest? Can you post code?

Comment: Maybe I'll post the code later, but for now, I'll just advise you go take a look at the commits and find out when the precompile method has been removed. Then look at the diff. It's pretty easy to readd the method. Someone forked sprockets at some point and made precompile return the manifest, try to search on google for that. But maybe you should try the gems people created, like the one below :)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Harry Brundage did a rewrite of my gem which uses more recent versions of everything, it's probably what you want to use:

https://github.com/hornairs/sprockets-rails

**Old suggestion:**

I've made a gem you can include in your Rails 3.0.x Gemfile which is an extraction of the Rails 3.1 sprockets integration:

https://github.com/jamesmacaulay/sprockets_rails3_backport

There are some differences from the Rails 3.1 behaviour, but they are well documented in the README. With most of the stuff you'd want to tweak, you can just uncomment the lines I've commented out.