# Trouble loading Rails Server (3.0.11, ruby 1.9.2), no such file to load -- sprockets/railtie (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

Using the Hartl tutorial.

Command: rails s

Response:

```
/Users/davidpardy/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:8:in `require': no such file     to load -- sprockets/railtie (LoadError)
    from /Users/davidpardy/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:8:in `<top     (required)>'
    from /Users/davidpardy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails    /commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Users/davidpardy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails    /commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/davidpardy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails    /commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/davidpardy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails    /commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

application.rb file below

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
#require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  #Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

Tried commenting out sprockets, just created more problems (and nothing came of that, unfortunately).

WUG thoughts?

Comment: Why not Rails 3.1.x?  Anyhow, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422755/how-to-use-sprockets-2-with-rails-3-0-x

Comment: Well, there is where the issue lies. I got to section 4.1.2 of the tutorial and had a slight error with the first 'css' update: where it makes the text a little prettier. Friend of mine suggested going back to rails 3 but he's a bit of a noob himself (as I am a noob, also). I'll post the link to that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738045/issue-loading-rails-3-server-after-coming-back-from-3-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've downgraded your app to rails 3.0 but there are still a number of places with your application references 3.1 only methods or files.

sprockets/railtie is one of those, there will also be settings in your environment.rb referring to the asset pipeline and probably some others too (the wrap params stuff springs to mind). You would need at the very least to remove all of those.

As someone new to rails I'd strongly suggest you start with the version of rails the tutorial you are following was written for and stick with it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Frederick. I totally agree with sticking with the version of the tutorial (rails 3). Long story short I started over fresh and this is the issue at hand (if we can call it that). When I'm in the home directory, its 1.9.2 and rails 3. same with first_app, same with demo_app. Then when I get to sample_app, it is ALWAYS 3.1.3 but I can switch the ruby between 1.9.2 and 1.9.3. When I try to run $ rvm 1.9.2-head@rails3011 ; rails -v it still keeps it in rails 3.1.3. Pretty sure I did the gemsets correctly from the RVM website.